# printing values of object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code that get values from a grid. Instead of printing the values, the grid is printing data in below object format. How to print values?

```
[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
```

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#check").click(function(){
        var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
        alert(rows);
    });
});
```

Comment: Which values are that? How do you want them to be printed?

Comment: following format.                                                                                      [{"empId": "1","fname": "Henry","lname":"Rey","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Software Engg","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"TigoAdmin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11"}]

Comment: That's [JSON](http://json.org). Just use `alert(JSON.stringify(rows))` - the `JSON` object is supported in every modern browser

Comment: sounds like JSOn structure isn't the same as plugin expects. Floow example docs and compare structures

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A simple way is to use

```
JSON.stringify(rows)
```

i.e.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(rows))
```

Else, you would need to manually traverse the object's properties and print them accordingly. Give more details about input and desired output for an example.

An example in interactive Node.js:

```
> x = { 1: 2, 3:4 };
{ '1': 2, '3': 4 }

> x.toString();
'[object Object]'

> JSON.stringify(x)
'{"1":2,"3":4}'
```

Comment: following format.                                                                                      [{"empId": "1","fname": "Henry","lname":"Rey","empcat":"Staff","dept":"IT","jTitle":"Software Engg","rAccess":"New Hire","lManager":"TigoAdmin","sDate":"2012-10-11","eDate":"2012-10-11"}]

Comment: exactly what stringify does, doesn't it? besides, you can add such additional information to the question itself, it makes the Q&A thread better to read.

Comment: do I need to include any related files for this? I am getting "JSON is undefined" error in IE.

Comment: Rudolf, your answer is precise and perfect!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print value of objects in JQuery you can create a new array with values and print it:

```
var array =  $.map(object, function(value){
    return value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Grid's getrows returns an array of rows. To get the first row: var row = rows[0]. To get the second row use: var row2 = rows[1] and so on.

To get the 'fname' cell value from the first row, you can do this:

```
var rows = $("#grid").jqxGrid('getrows');
var firstRow = rows[0];
var fnameValue = firstRow.fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got help from  stackoverflow, Include following jquery function:

```
   The result will be equivalent to the PHP function print_r.
   echo '<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>';

   USAGE: 
   var data = [{'id':1,'name':'hello'},'world'];
   $('#element').print_r(data);

//==========================================
(function($) {

    $.fn.print_r = $.fn.print = function(variable){
        return this.each(function(){
        if(typeof variable == 'object'){
            var string = $.print_r.objectToString(variable,0);
            $(this).html(string);
        } else {
            $(this).html('<pre>'+variable.toString()+'</pre>');
        }
    });

    }

    $.print_r = {
            objectToString : function (variable,i){
              var string = '';
              if(typeof variable == 'object' && i < 3){ // 3 is to prevent endless recursion, set higher for more depth
                  string += 'Object ( <ul style="list-style:none;">';
                  var key;
                  for(key in variable) {
                      if (variable.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        string += '<li>['+key+'] => ';
                        string += $.print_r.objectToString(variable[key],i+1);
                        string += '</li>';
                      }
                  }
                  string += '</ul> )';
              } else {
                  string = variable.toString();
              }
              return string;
        }
    }

})(jQuery)
```